# Ошибка циклического импорта

Tags: python, telebot, python-import

Пишу тг бота. Попытался вынести функцию в отдельный файл. И получил ImportError.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'remote' from partially initialized module 'generate_command' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Вот код двух файлов:

https://pastebin.com/ham3M8VF - pcremote.py

https://pastebin.com/Sii7FwJn - generate_command.py

Comment: Подумайте над своим кодом и преобразуйте его так, чтобы не нужно было из ваших модулей импортировать друг друга. Разбейте ваш код ещё на отдельные модули, например.

Comment: @CrazyElf и правда, спасибо!!!